# Flash CS6 AS3: Else If statement

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, if-statement

I explained this earlier and got a good answer. For some reason it's not working out as I want it to. I have a counter counting down from 15 seconds. I want the users to input " 4 8 15 16 23 42" and then click a button or hit enter. This would then launch a different scene bumping the counter back up to 1:08:00..

But if they don't put the numbers in before the counter hit zero I want it to display a different scene of the computer blowing up or shaking violently. Here is the code I got earlier. But once I hit the button it just restarts at 15 seconds opposed to playing my new scene.

EDIT: Just found out if you type in any numbers, not even correct ones, it starts the counter back at 15.

import flash.events.MouseEvent;
submitbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, testPassword);
function testPassword(e:MouseEvent):void { if (numbertext.text == "4 8 15 16 23 42") { gotoAndPlay("success");

} else { gotoAndPlay("shake");

}

}

Comment: if you guys need sample of my timeline I'll post a picture. I'm such a noob with flash!

Comment: if my answer work, you may want to accept it ...

Answer (score 1):

First thing, is that this will work only if you click with the mouse, so you should add the listener if you want to add the possibility to press enter,

and gotoAndPlay in as3 is like `gotoAndPlay(frameNumber, "sceneName");` 
so your function should be :

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent; 
submitbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, testPassword); 

function testPassword(e:MouseEvent):void { 
if (numbertext.text == "4 8 15 16 23 42") { 
     gotoAndPlay(1, "success");
} else { 
     gotoAndPlay(1, "shake");
  }
}
```

And about the timer, be sure that when you instanciate it, you do it this way,

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(15000,1); // 15sec and just 1 time
```

and the listener should be `TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE`

But what you need to do, is to read the documentation, may be some tutorials too, to learn the basics ...

Comment: Perfect, I got this to work perfectly for me! Except I need to go back and add in the enter option because it doesn't work unless the user clicks the button I made for them!

Comment: [MovieClip](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html)